# Airflow ignores catchup=False when starting compose

Tags: python, docker-compose, airflow

this is my dag definition:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 5, 8),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
    'catchup_by_default' : False,
    'catchup':False
}

# Everyday at 9 am
with DAG(dag_id="spotify_etl", default_args=default_args,catchup=False, schedule="0 9 * * *") as dag:
```

However i stopped the compose yesterday and today at 10:30 am I started it, and the dag ran, although it is set to run at 9am and catchup is set to False,
I even defined

````
    'catchup':False```
in default_args yet it still catches up
````

Comment: Did the dag run from 2023-05-08 to the day you turned it on? If not, then your issue isn't related to `catchup`.